# how to customize listMonth view of full calendar js

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullcalendar

```
calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                height: 552,
                headerToolbar: {
                    left: '',
                    center: 'prev today title,next',
                    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,resourceTimeGridDay,listMonth'
                },
                
                dayMaxEvents: true,
                navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
                editable: false,
                selectable: true,
                allDaySlot: false,
                customRender: true,
                titleFormat: { // will produce something like "Tuesday, September 18, 2018"
                    day: 'numeric',
                    month: 'short',
                    year: 'numeric'
                },
                refetchResourcesOnNavigate: true,
                businessHours: getBusinessHours(),
                resources :"{{route('front.appointment.get_appointment_dashboard')}}?resouce=1",
                events: url,
                eventDidMount: function(el) {
                    addBtn();
                },

                eventContent: function(info) {

                    if (info.view.type == "listMonth") {
                        return '';
                    }
                    if (info.view.type == 'dayGridMonth') {
                        if (info.event.allDay == false) {
                            return {
                                html: '<div style=""><div class="fc-daygrid-event-dot change_color-'+info.event.extendedProps.resourceId+'" id="fc-daygrid-'+info.event.extendedProps.resourceId+'" style="border-color: ' +
                                    info.event.borderColor + ';">  </div> <div class="fc-event-time">' +
                                    info.event.extendedProps.time + '</div><div class="fc-event-title">' + (info.event.extendedProps.customer || 'Empty') + '&nbsp; &nbsp;' + (info.event.extendedProps.LastName || '')+ ' </div> </div>'
                            }
                        } else {
                            return {

                                html: '<div class="fc-event-main" style="color: ' + info.textColor +
                                    ';"><div class="fc-event-main-frame"><div class="fc-event-title-container"><div class="fc-event-title fc-sticky">' +
                                    (info.event.extendedProps.customer || 'Empty') +
                                    ' </div></div></div></div><div class="fc-event-resizer fc-event-resizer-end"></div>'
                            }
                        }
```

i want to make a table that have header and borders and my data in that table

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please checkout the [tour], [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and [ask]. Please add more details to your question to clarify what your issue is.

Comment: Can you be more specific please? What _exactly_ do you want? listMonth view is already a table. Do you mean a table inside an event or something? A sample screenshot might really help us. And also, where exactly are you getting stuck? Please provide some commentary on your efforts so far and the results it's producing. That way, we have a clear starting point, without needing to guess or make assumptions. Thanks.